# how to run terraform azure infrastructure code to create environment

Tags: terraform

At the moment, I am running my terraform from my laptop which is obviously less than ideal:

```
module "eu_resource_group" {
  source                        = "./modules/resource_groups"

  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  resource_group_location       = var.location
}

module "vault" {
  source                        = "./modules/vault"

  resource_group_name           = module.eu_resource_group.eu_resource_group_name
  resource_group_location       = module.eu_resource_group.eu_resource_group_location
}

module "storage" {
  source                        = "./modules/storage"

  resource_group_name           = module.eu_resource_group.eu_resource_group_name
  resource_group_location       = module.eu_resource_group.eu_resource_group_location

  storage_account_name          = var.storage_account_name
  storage_container_name        = var.storage_container_name
}
```

I would like to run this from azure.

How would I run this from azure. Creating an azure devops project creates a CI pipeline etc.

How are people running their terraform infrastructure code in a non-local environment?

Comment: This question is a little broad in its current form. "How people run Terraform non-local?" isn't going to have one concrete answer, everyone has different needs and use cases. Maybe you could try in Azure DevOps Pipeline and then update your question with any issues you have getting it to work this way?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes - you need to create new Azure DevOps pipeline and configure everything there (code location, secrets, service principal, etc.). There a lot of step-by-step guides, like [this (medium)](https://medium.com/@gmusumeci/deploying-terraform-infrastructure-using-azure-devops-pipelines-step-by-step-d58b68fc666d) or [this one (azure devops labs)](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/terraform/).
Also, don't forget about storing Terraform [remote state on Azure](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/azurerm.html).